# Is it possible to learn a language entirely by observation?

Tags: internal-consistency, language

It is the age of exploration. Intrepid European colonists have come to settle the Americas amidst a storm of interest over the wondrous materials that may be found in the New World. Unfortunately for them, the indigenous have spent thousands of years cultivating their magic, distinguishing themselves in appearance, thought, language, and most severely: power. By the time of Christopher Columbus, the gulf has become so wide that the indigenous cannot even recognize people from the Old World as rational beings - regarding them instead as curiosities and pests beneath consideration.

These unfortunate circumstances have stymied European expansion into the continent, and unable to meaningfully combat the indigenous, the colonial powers have instead sought to broker communication between their peoples in the hopes that the use of familiar language will elevate themselves in their eyes. This is no easy task, given the [usual methods](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90624/learning-a-new-language-without-any-reference) for learning learning language through immersion are infeasible; intrepid linguists must observe from a distance lest they be discovered and potentially killed.

Altogether, the question stands: is this possible? Can a dedicated force of 16th century linguists learn an alien language through observation alone, given any sort of contact is likely to result in death? On what sort of timescale can this be achieved? I will accept any answer giving a historical example of any language having been successfully studied (grammar, lexicon, etc. to fluency) this way at any point in history.

**Misc.:**

- Capturing indigenous is impossible
- It is possible to remain hidden within earshot of the indigenous
- Infiltrating indigenous camps, towns, and other kinds of settlement or buildings is very dangerous
- Acquiring indigenous artifacts is incredibly difficult, even if they have been abandoned
- For simplicity's sake, we can imagine there's only one language
- The indigenous language is not too far removed from real ones
- The colonists are fielding technology roughly in line with what their real counterparts had
- The colonists are allowed to have anachronistic culture or knowledge, however
- Europe is desperate for successful colonies; the wondrous materials native to the continent are as valuable to them as modern technology would be to Rome

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130242/discussion-on-question-by-smallobsession-is-it-possible-to-learn-a-language-enti).

Comment: You don’t seek to colonize the territory of a power that considers you bugs to be squashed when convenient.  You may aspire to trade, colonization ambitions  should be limited to hoping they don’t decide to spray your territory and move in after the bugs are gone.

Comment: Boy, imagine writing this stuff, but reversing the races. Seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: @jmoreno You do when the native resources provide you with the means to conquer the rest of the world. Imagine what you could do with paper-thin armor that can stop cannon balls and dead-simple devices that produce infinite energy. Furthermore, trade is an outside prospect simply because it draws attention to the Old World - a prospect every imperial power dreads. It helps that being relatively small helps them stay unnoticed by all but a few coastal tribes, and having written off South America as inhospitable (greater scale factor), they've avoided waking the sleeping dragon.

Comment: @Davor Why? This is fiction of a very ridiculous sort. The only message you could really get out of half the stories I intend to write is "imperialism bad", just with the twist that it's not only bad for the natives, but for the laymen of the imperial powers sent into the meatgrinder or dying back home in pointless wars. The differentiated forms are simply because I needed a bigger gap to justify the other themes: miscommunication & assumption, the banality of evil, and guilt for what can't be helped. Is there something I'm not thinking of? This culture war business is very confusing.

Comment: @smallobsession I think you missed jmoreno's point.  It's not that you don't want to colonize them, it's that you can't.  How are you going to conquer a culture with armor that can easily stop your biggest weapons, while their own weapons can kill your entire armies in an instant?

Comment: @smallobsession - go ahead and write a story where a bunch of black africans are so primitive they can't even be recognized as rational people, and see what happens. But for your sake, do it anonymously.

Comment: @Ryan_L Ah, I see. Yes, the imperial powers can only colonize the Americas insofar as they can establish colonies/settlements. You are both entirely right that they cannot meaningfully conquer the land they build these colonies on and exist entirely at the mercy (more often, ignorance) of the indigenous. The continent is big enough that this should be possible, but may make for a good question if you have reason to disagree.

Comment: @Davor Please try to avoid inflammatory language; there is no need to be uncivil. I apologize if my own has come across that way. Regarding technology, the indigenous are not powerful because they are technologically advanced, but because they are giants. As for their lack of recognition of European technology, it is a more complicated story. 1. most of it is too small to inspect, 2. wild animals force buildings to emphasize integrity & stealth (domes, mounds, etc.), 3. machines look like insects and they have no reason to believe otherwise, etc. In short: who pays attention to ants?

Comment: @smallobsession - aren't you just proving my point now? What is inflammatory in my comment besides the race swap?

Comment: @Davor How am I proving your point? If the colonists were literally microscopic, this would be obvious. If the colonists used biotech exclusively, we'd have one of several classic sci-fi's. Study ancient myth, and you'll see Stymphalian Birds and Myrmekes before misshapen, babbling people the size of insects. RE: inflammatory, your post is emotionally charged, condescending towards Africans, and gives an implicit threat (from others). To answer the point directly, there are people today who do not recognize Africans as rational; to write about it could do good in ousting these prejudices.

Comment: @smallobsession - you're proving my point by calling my post "inflammatory, ... emotionally charged, condescending towards Africans" just because I did a race swap. That's exactly what I claimed would happen, and you demonstrated that I was right. You do you, guy, and good luck with that. I have to no horse in this race.

Comment: @Davor If you seriously cannot see why calling a group of people from ANY organized culture a "bunch" is not condescending to them, or that exaggerating ("*so* primitive") and misrepresenting the situation (c.f. Greek myths named) isn't inflammatory, then I am honestly lost for words. Why are you participating in this pointless (culture) war? No good will come of it.

Comment: An important plot point of _The 13th Warrior_ is that the protagonist learns the language of his traveling companions (who initially dislike him) simply by listening to their daily conversation for months. This isn't proof that it's actually possible, but there is precedent in fiction.

Comment: @smallobsession Davor made no threat, that's silly.

Comment: @smallobsession Why can't the Europeans demonstrate intelligence using e.g. mathematics and, for arguments sake, fire? If I saw a bunch of small fires grouped in groups of prime numbers, or a geometric sequence, I'd infer human agency. This isn't a frame challenge, but as I see it, an unaddressed plot hole.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The real-life process corresponding to the requirements is learning a foreign language by watching TV shows in that language (without subtitles). This ranges from trivially easy if the foreign language is closely related to a language that the learner already knows (e.g., a Romanian learning Italian from watching [*La piovra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_piovra) on Bulgarian TV), to relatively easy if the languages are closely related but not very (e.g., the same Romanian watching [*Escrava Isaura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Escrava_Isaura_(2004_TV_series)) and [*Avenida Paulista*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209550) on the same Balgarska televizia), to somewhat difficult if the two languages are only distantly related (e.g., learning enough Bulgarian to follow football commentary of live matches), to very difficult but far from impossible if the target language is completely alien (e.g., a Romanian attempting to watch Hungarian TV).

<sup>In the 1980s, Romanian state television had degenerated to such a great extent that it went on air only two hours per day, and those were dedicated to Communist propaganda. This created an environment where everybody who could watched TV shows from neighbouring countries; Bulgaria in the south, Yugoslavia in the south-east, Hungary in the west; and even Soviet TV was watched in the east.</sup>

The point is that humans have a built-in ability to learn foreign languages. This ability is highest in childhood, but it never goes away completely; and moreover, if instead of casually watching foreign TV shows the learners do have an actual incentive, the results will be even better and the learning faster.

As for formal examples, we do now know several dead languages which were desciphered entirely by closely examining ancient texts; for example, [Hittite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hittite_language).

Comment: That's a good analogy and some interesting history! My only concern here is that without feedback, it's possible to get an incorrect understanding of the grammar, preventing you from speaking fluently - even if you can understand well enough. Are there records of Hungarians commenting on their skill? Regarding Hittite at least, scholars had the benefit of the writing system being shared with other languages allowing them to work backwards. Altogether, I will probably accept this answer if no-one shows up with something more definite, since matter of Romanian TV probably satisfies my criteria.

Comment: @smallobsession: Bad grammar never stopped anybody. As the saying goes, broken English is *the* international language. Have you never bought a cheap and functional device made in China with an instruction manual written in sort-of English? Or, for that matter, do you think that the Iberians, the Gauls, the Dacians and so on ever learned proper Latin grammar? (Fun factoid: archaeologists have found a cache of honest for-real letters written in sort-of Latin by a Greek of Alexandria, who had joined the Roman army and was proud of his language skills; so we *know* how bad it was.)

Comment: Another example is Dutch and German. In the 60s, 70s and into the 80's Dutch TV was limited to just 2 channels. A lot of Dutch people got a basic  knowledge of German just by watching the German channels (3 to 6 depending on location). Of course Dutch and German are closely related. I only got German at school from age 13, but before that my vocabulary of German curse words was probably bigger than my Dutch repertoire. German Krimis (detective series) were (and still are) high quality and very popular and had a lot of colorful language.

Comment: @smallobsession The research shows that correction has almost no benefit in language learning, and listening is much, much more important than speaking.

Comment: @smallobsession Broken grammar isn't a substantial problem.  People who learn a language as an adult will generally have somewhat broken grammar, as well as problems where they have one word but the language they have learned has multiple words.

Comment: As infiltrating the indigenous towns is highly dangerous, the analogy of passively watching TV shows starts to fall apart. Many areas of life will not be observable, unlike with TV. If all you ever saw was football match commentaries, your chances of learning enough language to barter, pray, or describe falling in love are greatly diminished..

Comment: @AlexP Bad grammar *ain't* never stopped *nobody*!

Comment: I got most of my english by playing videogames that had no translation for my language when I was a young lad - mostly RPGs.

Comment: @user253751: *"Ain't"* for *"<auxiliary_verb> not"* is perfectly good grammar; but unfortunately it is good grammar in a low status [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)), or a low [prestige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics)) dialect or sociolect. The use of this form does not identify the speaker as lacking grammatical knowledge, it identifies the speaker as being low class or belonging to a low status group.

Comment: @AlexP - just because ebonics became mainstream for PC reasons, doesn't mean it's good English.

Comment: @Davor: *Ain't* and double negatives have nothing to do with the English dialect stereotypically associated with Americans of sub-Saharan African descent. They are perfectly normal grammatical features of several English dialects and sociolects which have nothing to do with black Americans. (And, generally speaking. There are many forms of good English, but they do not all have the same prestige. There is a standard form of the language; or, in the case of English, more than one -- English is pluricentric. Then there are geographical dialects, registers of varying formality, and so on.)

Comment: @AlexP The triple negative is bad grammar. Agreed re: ain't.

Comment: @AlexP Ain't = 1, never = 2, nobody = 3. If interpreted completely literally, they aren't direct negations of one another, but then, if interpreted literally, it's not saying what we all take it to mean. It's an idiom that uses three negatives for rhetorical effect, and in doing so expresses the idea that "It never stopped anyone" in an unclear and needlessly circuituitous manner. Purely as a matter of grammar, it's bad. As a means of communication, it works fine, and the fact that the idiom is so widely understood outside its homeland suggests that the rhetorical element is effective.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant: If it is an idiom it cannot be gramatically incorrect. On the contrary, if the grammar book cannot explain how a well-known idiom works, it is the grammar book which is defective. By definition, grammar is a description of the language in actual use. But it may be that the grammar book simply refers to a different form of the language, where the construction is not allowed. (For example, in 1970s Romania, all English grammar books referred to 1950s standard British English.) (And it's not triple negation anyway, because *never* and *nobody* are parallel determinants.)

Comment: P.S. To understand why it's not triple negation, consider its translation in the standard form of Romance languages, where double negation is an absolute syntactic requirement: French *une mauvaise gramnmaire **n**'a **jamais** arrêté **personne***; Italian *una cattiva grammatica **non** ha **mai** fermato **nessuno***; Romanian *gramatica proastă **nu** a oprit **niciodată** pe **nimeni***. I am not familiar with any form of English where *ain't never stopped nobody* is correctly formed, but I strongly belive that in such a dialect \*\**ain't never stopped anybody* would be wrong.

Comment: @AlexP Disagree. Even in the society where it came from, it would not be allowed in formal or technical writing, as if interpreted literally, it's simply incorrect, basically nonsensical. (I addressed the parallel determinants already). Some idioms/colloquialisms actually do employ bad grammar, and this is one of them.

Comment: "If interpreted completely literally, they aren't direct negations of one another" Come on, I addressed the parallel determinants already. That's a fruitless tangent.

Comment: @AlexP Constructions like "Ain't never stopped anyone" are common enough. Whether they're used in areas geographically separated from those where  the full blown "triple negative" construction is used, I'd have to check, but I doubt it.

Comment: "By definition, grammar is a description of the language in actual use" No. That would validate the 'grammar' of any two people who decide as a pair to use any particular construction. It'd even apply when the two people *believe it's grammatically incorrect*. There has to be some notion of widespread or universally acknowledged intelligibility built into the term grammar, or it ceases to be a meaningful term distinct from 'locally intelligible'.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant: The personal idiom of any one speaker is not the *language*, it is the personal idiom of that specific speaker. The *language* is the linguistic communication system common to all speakers. The distinction is universally recognized in linguistics, beginning with Saussure's discussion of [*langue et parole*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_and_parole) in his [*Course in General Linguistics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_in_General_Linguistics) (1916). So yes, it is meaningful to speak of grammatically incorrect utterances produced by any one speaker.

Comment: @AlexP Right, agreed. And grammar is the rules of a *language*. It's your "idioms can't be ungrammatical" / "grammar is defined by how the language is used in practice (with no reference to rules/structure or the notion of widespread acceptance thereof) that I object to. You can't make a grammatical silk purse out of a "Ain't never to nobody" sow's ear.

Answer (score 7):

Some people in real life speak Klingon. There is even a popular story in the internet about a couple who only had Klingon as a common language between them, and they married.

Elvish is also a con language and some people speak it.

Even The Elder Scroll's Dov language has some enthusiasts.

I doubt that Tolkien and the producers for Star Trek and Skyrim were giving Zoom classes. Somebody had to reverse engineer each one before people could use them.

Comment: Klingon, Sindarin, and Quenya all had extensive documentation available to fans aside from just what appeared in the primary media. And Skyrim's language is only slightly removed from a straight cipher of English. None of those are really comparable situations.

Comment: @LogabR.Kearsley Still people using that documentation were observing it rather than getting taught by a teacher.

Comment: Yes, but "observing" documentation intended to explain how the language works is far, far different from simply observing the language in use with no explanation.

Comment: Someone had not only to reverse-engineer these languages, but to engineer them all the way to a complete language as well.

Comment: Not "documentation" in the sense of "documents written in the language" - "documentation" in the sense of dictionaries.  Klingon as a complete language first appears in the 3rd Star Trek film, and the person who devised it for them (Marc Okrand) published *The Klingon Dictionary* the next year.  Tolkien may not have had Zoom but he discussed the workings of his Elvish languages at length in appendices and footnotes, and many of the examples of Elvish in *Lord of the Rings* appear with English translations.

Comment: Dov seems to have something similar in the shape of in-game English translations of large numbers of inscriptions in Dov.  So while it's possible that there may have been conlangs like that that people "reverse-engineered", Klingon, Elvish, and Dov certainly aren't evidence of it.

Comment: On Elvish: legend goes that Tolkien wrote the LotR books as a vessel for his conlangs.

Answer (score 7):

**Is it possible to learn a language entirely by observation?**

Yes, mere observation can be enough to learn a language... but that method *will* absolutely require much more time to do so than traditional immersion.

For example, there are plenty of anecdotal examples of children who seem basically mute until suddenly showing the ability to speak in full sentences.  Usually, though, those full sentences come at a time that lags years behind the normal development of their peers who've progressed through basic words, to broken sentences, to simple sentences, quite some time ago.

There might be a bigger barrier to deal with, however...

> "... regarding them instead as curiosities and pests beneath consideration..."

> "... any sort of contact is likely to result in death..."

This is perhaps the trickiest bottleneck for your story/setting; depending on where you draw the line for "enough fluency to not be killed".

If something like *"We, a Lesser People, ask your Great People to teach us your wonderful language!"* is sufficient to pique their curiosity, then you can probably reach that level in a relatively short time frame (maybe a year or so, more depending on the language's particularities and difficulties).  And from there, they can throw a kindergarten-level teacher at your explorers and start a more typical language-immersion process.

If you need to come out strong with a fancy spiel in full-legalese like *"On behalf of King X of Y, heir to the Z of Q, conqueror of the R, Lord over the protectorate of S, long may he reign, we, his hired explorers, beseech thee to parlay on the matter of his vassals being deigned vermin in your lands and holdings, etc. ..."* then that will be much harder and take substantially more time to develop.  The particular thorniness of the issue being that you just won't have access to much of that vocabulary when eavesdropping on farmers near the outskirts of civilization.  So, not only would you have to sneak further into dangerous territory to learn the important stuff... but you'd probably need a significant time investment to learn just the basics beforehand to understand *any* of the more complicated stuff by building off of context clues.

Comment: Very interesting idea with mutism! I will have to do some reading to verify, since I only know about it in passing. As for the proficiency, the former would be more than sufficient evidence in the setting I intend, although I lean towards higher proficiency due to the fact plans rarely survive first contact with the enemy, so anyone in that role may not have the luxury of being able to use a script.

Comment: On reflection, it occurred to me that the situations aren't as comparable as first thought; parents will "baby-talk" for their children, pointing out objects and actions clearly. Even a mute adult would have the benefit of being drug around and gestured at, giving additional context that native speakers would rarely provide eachother.

Comment: @smallobsession You're right that the mute-child example is more of a one-way immersion rather than a non-immersion.  However, the example still holds somewhat on account of the fact that the "full sentences" the child speaks aren't just parrotings of the baby talk the parents attempted to teach - and instead those sentences show an absorption and synthesis of the many examples of speech the child might have heard even when not being directly addressed.  While it is true your linguists won't be spoon-fed basic nouns and verbs, the do have the luxury of understanding language as a high concept.

Comment: @smallobsession And the colonists will not observe the natives teaching their children??

Comment: @LorenPechtel I am kicking myself for not having realized that. Very good point.

Answer (score 3):

In many ways, this is what the [Generative Pre-trained Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3) series of AI projects is doing in practice.  Feed the algorithm an incredibly large body of English text, and it leans how to converse in English.

While not exactly what you are looking for, and doesn't really answer if it is possible for a human, it does show the task is in and of itself possible.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but this assumes that the AI possesses an *understanding* of English and not "just" the ability to give an appropriate response in the manner of the Chinese Room. This remains an unsolved philosophical question, so it either option is possible.

Comment: Welcome Chuu, this really might have been better posted as a comment than an answer. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy worldbuilding.

Comment: They should put to work on recognizing the dolphin language.

Answer (score 1):

If your idea was the old science fiction cliche idea that an alien civilization can learn our languages just by watching TV shows I should say that no, you can not learn a language entirely by observation.

But I remembered a good movie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_13th_Warrior
where Antonio Banderas character learned Vikings language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangians just by observation.

In the movie, Banderas is a noble Arabic language speaking Muslim. I was told by an old English language teacher of mine that Arabic speaking people have facility to learn foreign languages. So, may be, there was cases people can learn a language entirely by observation.

Any way, if you are dropped into a place where no one knows your language, the written system is totally different (think on Japanese or Hebrew) and you are left there forever, well, you ought to learn your new home language entirely by observation:).

Comment: (1) [Muslin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslin) is a fabric. Banderas played a Musli**m**. (2) The last paragraph of the answer refers to a method of learning foreign languages known as [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_immersion). It works very very well. The question is explicitly asking for a situation where it is not possible to interact with speakers of the target language.

Comment: Thank you point my typo.  I answered the question in the very first paragraph! I write about an old cliche used by bad science fiction movies. Same situation but different contexts and similar conclusion: it is not possible fully learn a language just by observation.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot approximate the exact amount of time it would take to learn a language that way. However, you can make things easier for yourself by inducing some luck in your story.

And by that I mean, you can have your linguist find and listen to the conversations that are happening inside one of their school. If they have any. Where they are teaching small children to speak their language.

Or any kind of family with a toddler where the parents or some adult is trying to teach their own language to the child.

And by listening to their conversations, which are meant to teach their own language to one of their children. The hopes of learning their language and learning it way faster than listening to casual conversations are way higher.

Comment: Depending on the language, this may not work. For example, the Japanese have keigo (lit. polite language). It is taught a little bit in school (close to graduation), but most people today have to take separate classes to be fluent in it. All major companies also have keigo training programmes for new hires.  Another example would be Russian profanities (it is a language of its own, don't confuse with English swearing words). Any native speaker of Russian is supposed to understand them but they are not taught officially anywhere. Moreover, this language is not used in front of outsiders.

Comment: I assumed they don't need to be perfect at this language. They only want to learn it to break the language barrier, so I just assumed that they would be interested in learning just the bare minimum. @otkin

Answer (score 0):

Learning language is a very developmental process.  It is the easiest when we are young and harder when we're older if the language's seperation points referred to as phonemes, differ considerably from our native language.

Its possible however simply because most language speakers tend to use the same phrases over and over with same filler words. You'd have to find someone who could point our nuances however.

Lets put it this way, we have translation dictionaries and europeans learned to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

As described it seems a immensely difficult task if it weren't you waved anachronistic knowledge. The colonist need to overcome several conditions basic to the learning of a new language:

**Understanding the social context:** values, traditions, institutions (political or civil) etc all that give it utility and reason to the use of language. Without it the misunderstanding might be endless.

**Sociolinguistical background:** learning a language implies social differentiation. Colonists would like to set their [sociolect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolect) to the right social group and social situation.

**Learning grammar:** grammar rules might have a high degree of complexity because of exceptions adding to the learning time.

So the colonists would need modern knowledge of anthropology, socio-linguistics and formal linguistics to overcome the lack of direct contact to language use.

They would be able to perform [crucial experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimentum_crucis) when they'd hit a block to the cost of getting some junior researchers killed.

I think they might be able to form a group of children in an isolated community where they'd only speak the target code. With this they might be able to show a "civilized" face after 30 to 40 years.

If they didn't have all that anachronistic knowledge it would take a social and scientific revolution to obtain them.

Answer (score 0):

**Frame challenge**. The whole situation can be basically boiled down to decryption of extinct language (obviously you can't speak with dead people who spoke said language), when there is no grammar textbook on said language.

One way to help this research is to find closest relatives for languages of Americas. And then use knowledge of said relatives for decryption of American languages.

It can be possible, as such relatives were found, or at the very least, were suspected to be found, see links below (maybe there are more):

> Dené–Yeniseian is a proposed language family consisting of the
> Yeniseian languages of central Siberia and the Na-Dené languages of
> northwestern North America.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Den%C3%A9%E2%80%93Yeniseian_languages

> The Eskaleut (/ɛˈskæliuːt/), Eskimo–Aleut or Inuit–Yupik–Unangan
> languages are a language family native to the northern portions of the
> North American continent and a small part of northeastern Asia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskaleut_languages

> Dené–Caucasian is a proposed language family that includes
> widely-separated language groups spoken in the Northern Hemisphere:
> Sino-Tibetan languages, Yeniseian languages, Burushaski and North
> Caucasian languages in Asia; Na-Dené languages in North America; and
> the Vasconic languages from Europe (including Basque).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Den%C3%A9%E2%80%93Caucasian_languages

And once you figured out some of American languages this way (i.e. learned it), you can use said knowledge to help decrypt other American languages, especially language of neighbors of speakers of said American language.